# Android Parcelable Parcel HashMap

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, parcelable, parcel

I want to use Parcelable instead of Serializable in android, because it is faster and recommended.
My question is, it seems i cannot parcel a LinkedHashMap, a class provided by Java, right?

So for example

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   LinkedHashMap<String,int> age;
   ...
   ....
}
```

How do I parcel this Person class?

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544781/is-it-possible-to-create-a-hashmap-that-is-parcelable-on-android), see if answer here helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

The best I have come up with so far is use Bundle instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Parceler](http://parceler.org) supports LinkedHashMap along with a variety of other standard Java collections.  To use Parceler, you'll just need to annotate your `Person` class and wrap/unwrap it into and from the generated `Parcelable`:

```
Person person = new Person();
Parcels.wrap(person);
...
Parcels.unwrap(parcelable);
```