# Use Parcelable with an Object with Hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, intentservice

I have an arrayList of objects stored in a class that extends intentService. It's instance variables for the object are:

```
int id;
String name;
HashMap<Long, Double> historicFeedData
```

I want to be able to pass this arrayList back to an Activity. I have read that Parcelable is the way to go when you want to pass objects from a service to an activity. My method for writing to a parcel looks like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(id);
     out.writeString(name);
     dest.writeMap(historicFeedData);
 }
```

I am not sure how to read the hashmap back in from the parcel though? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388356/android-parcelable-parcel-hashmap) suggested using Bundle but I am unsure what they meant. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

If you're implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) you need to have a static Parcelable.Creator field called CREATOR that creates your object - see doco RE createFromParcel()

```
 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };
```

Then in your constructor that takes a Parcel you need to read the fields you wrote **in the same order.**

Parcel has a method called readMap(). Note you need to pass a classloader for the type of object in your HashMap. Since yours is storing doubles it might also work with null passed as the ClassLoader. Something like ...

```
in.readMap(historicFeedData, Double.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Thanks DEnizmveli for your ans, But i have one problem i think you can help. I have ArrayList<HashMap<String, Boolean>> which i want to write to parcel and then read it in next activity. Can you please guide how to do that ?