# Android - passing hashmap through intent

Tags: java, android, hashmap, parcelable, serializable

I'm trying to pass a Hashmap of custom objects through an intent.

I am trying to use parcelable as that's what i read is the correct way to do things in android (i.e. parcelable over serializable).

However, when i try and get the hashmap using getParcelable, it can't find my hashmap in the intent, but getSerializable can.

Is it OK to use serializable for hashmaps? Is this my only option?

Comment: You might encode simple maps as JSON or use static variables (duh).

Comment: Possible duplicated:


 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544781/is-it-possible-to-create-a-hashmap-that-is-parcelable-on-android
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities

Comment: Can you post your code for reading and writing to the parcelable.

Comment: @just lerning - i don't think i can use a static variable as the data is coming from any number of possible apps and being used in a library. Also it starts in Json but is multiple rows deep. I want to process the Json only once into a much simpler data structure and pass that around rather than passing the Json and having to process it multiple times

Comment: @RussWheeler Okay, you are 100% right. You cannot use static variables across apps. JSON was just a suggestion for simple maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course serialize your map, as long as your Objects are serializable. What you also could do is creating a separate singleton class (DataStore or so?) that saved your data. This way you don't need to pass the data from Activity to Activity. Or, even simpler, save the data in a public static variable.

Comment: What maybe i should've added is this data is starting out in any number of apps that include one common library. The data is passed into activities inside the library so i don't think i can use a public static as I'm not going to know the name of the activity for certain as it's possible each app will have a different activity where the data originates

Comment: No one said the data needs to be stored in the Activity. You can create some kind of data storage class in the library. Either use a singleton pattern for it, or static variables.

Comment: Not stored per se, but if I pass it from Activity A (in the local app) into Activity B in the library, then I at least need to grab it out of the intent from A and put it into the intent in B. Yes I could just put it straight from A to B but either way I've got to pass it from intent to intent to intent. I'd like to just be able to read the hashmap in the local app, directly in the library

Comment: When you use a static variable or a singleton datastore, you don't need to pass it in the Intent. Here's the simplest way: create a helper Class in your library containing a static Hashmap. Activity A saves the Hashmap into to helper class and then calls Activity B. Activity B gets the data from the helper class.

Comment: This sounds like a great answer. I've not tested it yet so I'll upvote the comment and then accept the answer when I get round to testing it. I've had to move on to a new piece of work as this was taking too long, but when I get back to it, I'll accept....if it works!

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) is not [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), so your options are:

- use put/getSerializable, which will work fine within your app
- encode the HashMap as json or another remotable format if sending outside your app
- take out the map entries one by one and put them in the Bundle directly (assuming they have string keys)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a "wrapper". It is ugly but working...

```
/**
 * Provides a way to wrap a serializable {@link Map} in order to preserve its class
 * during serialization inside an {@link Intent}, otherwise it would be "flattened"
 * in a {@link android.os.Parcel} and unparceled as a {@link java.util.HashMap}.
 */
public class MapWrapper<T extends Map & Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private final T map;

    public MapWrapper(@NonNull T map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public T getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * Add extra map data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example
     * the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".
     * <p>
     * The provided map will be wrapped to preserve its class during serialization.
     * Use {@link #getMapExtra(Intent, String)} to deserialize it.
     *
     * @param intent The intent to add data to.
     * @param name   The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
     * @param map    The map data value.
     *
     * @return The same {@link Intent} object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.
     *
     * @see Intent#putExtra(String, Serializable)
     */
    @NonNull
    public static <T extends Map & Serializable> Intent putMapExtra(
            @NonNull Intent intent, @NonNull String name, @NonNull T map) {
        return intent.putExtra(name, new MapWrapper<>(map));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve extra map data from the intent.
     *
     * @param intent The intent to retrieve data from.
     * @param name   The name of the desired extra item.
     *
     * @return The value of an extra map item that was previously added with
     * {@link #putMapExtra(Intent, String, Map)} or {@code null} if no data was found.
     *
     * @throws ClassCastException
     * If the {@link Serializable} object with the specified name is not of type
     * {@link MapWrapper} or if the wrapped {@code Map} is not of type {@link T}.
     * 
     * @see Intent#getSerializableExtra(String)
     */
    @Nullable
    public static <T extends Map & Serializable> T getMapExtra(
            @NonNull Intent intent, @NonNull String name)
            throws ClassCastException {
        final Serializable s = intent.getSerializableExtra(name);
        //noinspection unchecked
        return s == null ? null : ((MapWrapper<T>)s).getMap();
    }

}
```

More informations on https://medium.com/the-wtf-files/the-mysterious-case-of-the-bundle-and-the-map-7b15279a794e