# passing java.util.map to another activity

Tags: android, jsoup, parcelable

I'm doing parse the website using `Jsoup`. 
I have a `Map<String, String> cookies` in `MainActivity`. 
And I need to pass the value `cookies` to `SecondActivity`. 
So I created a class implements `Pracelable`.

#### MainActivity class :

```java
DataPasser dataPass = new DataPasser(id, pw, cookies);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", dataPass);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

#### SecondActivity class :

```java
dataPasser dataPass = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
String id = dataPass.getId();
String pw = dataPass.getPw();
Map<String, String> cookies = dataPass.getCookies();
```

#### the class implements `Parcelable`:

```java
public class DataPasser implements Parcelable {

    private String id;
    private String pw;
    Map<String, String> cookies;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPw() {
        return pw;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCookies() {
        return cookies;
    }

    public DataPasser(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readString();
        this.pw = in.readString();
        in.readMap(cookies, Map.class.getClassLoader()); /** NullPointerException here. **/
    }

    public DataPasser(String id, String pw, Map<String, String> cookies) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pw = pw;
        this.cookies = cookies;
    }


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(id);
        out.writeString(pw);
        out.writeMap(cookies);        
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataPasser> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DataPasser>() {
        public DataPasser createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DataPasser(in);
        }
        public DataPasser[] newArray (int size) {
            return new DataPasser[size];
        }
    };    
}
```

#### Error Log :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.hsk.hallymloginprac, PID: 8071
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hsk.hallymloginprac/com.hsk.hallymloginprac.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2305)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readMap(Parcel.java:1575)
>                                                                              at com.hsk.hallymloginprac.DataPasser.(DataPasser.java:37)
>                                                                              at com.hsk.hallymloginprac.DataPasser$1.createFromParcel(DataPasser.java:83)
>                                                                              at com.hsk.hallymloginprac.DataPasser$1.createFromParcel(DataPasser.java:81)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2111)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
>                                                                              at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
>                                                                              at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1206)
>                                                                              at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5292)
>                                                                              at com.hsk.hallymloginprac.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:44)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

But, I got a `NullPointerException` in `DataPasser` class. 
How can I pass `Map<String, String>` to another activity?

Comment: When you say It's because of Exception, Then it's always a good habit to post StackTrace.

Comment: Have you initialised the map you are passing. Check any corner cases where the cookies array might be null.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Okay. I didn't know that. I added StackTrace just now.

Comment: What's your line 83 in `DataPasser` class?

Comment: @n.arrow001 I tried that. No Exception. But, `cookies` not passed to `SecondActivity`.

Comment: @MrNeo `DataPasser` is the class that implements `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is to implement `Serializable` interface in `DataPasser`

```
public class DataPasser implements Serializable {
```

Pass data from `MainActivity.java` like you did

```
DataPasser dataPass = new DataPasser(id, pw, cookies);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", dataPass);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And get same in `SecondActivity.java` like this

```
DataPasser dataPass = (DataPasser) getIntent().getExtras().get("data");
```

and then access elements of `DataPasser`.

It works fine for my pojo classes.

Hope it'll work.

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737343/android-passing-hashmap-through-intent) also for `Parcelable`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't identify your actual issue but what I can suggest is to use [writeBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeBundle(android.os.Bundle)) instead of [writeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeMap(java.util.Map)). As per the documentation too, It is strongly recommended to use `writeBundle(Bundle)` instead of this method, since the Bundle class provides a type-safe API that allows you to avoid mysterious type errors at the point of marshaling.

You can easily read the data using [readBundle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readBundle(java.lang.ClassLoader)) which was written with [writeBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeBundle(android.os.Bundle)). It will
Read and return a new Bundle object from the parcel at the current `dataPosition()`. If again the issue raised then please kindly comment.

**UPDATE**

As taken an example of Person, Simply your `writeToParcel` looks like this,

```
 @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // create a bundle for the key value pairs
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        // insert the key value pairs to the bundle
        bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        bundle.putInt(KEY_AGE, age);

        // write the key value pairs to the parcel
        dest.writeBundle(bundle);
    }
```

And `createFromParcel` method looks like this,

```
@Override
        public Person createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // read the bundle containing key value pairs from the parcel
            Bundle bundle = source.readBundle();

            // instantiate a person using values from the bundle
            return new Person(bundle.getString(KEY_NAME),
                                bundle.getInt(KEY_AGE));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please give me simple example code?

Comment: @Chris I have added simple example in update have a look.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can try. Try replacing

```
public DataPasser(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readString();
    this.pw = in.readString();
    in.readMap(cookies, Map.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

with

```
public DataPasser(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readString();
    this.pw = in.readString();
    in.readMap(cookies, String.class.getClassLoader()); 
}
```

Because, according to the documentation of Parcel.java, the method readMap is

```
public final void readMap(Map outVal, ClassLoader loader) {
    int N = readInt();
    readMapInternal(outVal, N, loader);
}
```

which calls

```
void readMapInternal(Map outVal, int N,
    ClassLoader loader) {
    while (N > 0) {
        Object key = readValue(loader);
        Object value = readValue(loader);
        outVal.put(key, value);
        N--;
    }
}
```

So here, readValue tries to load values of type map as 'key' and 'value' for map.
readValue returns null hence values of 'key' and 'value' are null for

```
outVal.put(key,value)
```

Hence the NullPointerException